# How to show only divs which dynamic attribute match

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I may be close but since apparently nobody asked something like this, perhaps I may ask with the wrong wording.

I have a tabber with categorys which are dynamic and fancy box-galleys which also have dynamic attributes (shown here as divs with the attribute lala="xyz"). So how can I show on click on the tabber (here as first and last buttons) only the matching gallerys (in my code the first two or the last two divs should diapear)?

NOTE: the attributes are not predictable.

My html:

```
<div class="wrap">
<div class="box" lala="ui">
  <p>This is my box. There are many like it, but this one is mine. 1</p>
</div>

<div class="box" lala="ui">
  <p>This is my box. There are many like it, but this one is mine. 2</p>
</div>

<div class="box" lala="uibui">
  <p>This is my box. There are many like it, but this one is mine. 3</p>
</div>

<div class="box" lala="uibui">
  <p>This is my box. There are many like it, but this one is mine. 4</p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="showall">Show all</div>
<br>
<div class="mybutton" lala="ui">SHOW ONLY UI</div>
<div class="mybutton" lala="uibui">SHOW ONLY UIBUI</div>
```

And my jquery:

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    $('.showall').click(function() {
        $('.box').show();
    });

    $('.mybutton').click(function () {
        var myattr = $(this).attr('lala');
        $(".box[lala]").not([myattr = "lala"]).hide();
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Answer works, just added a line to show the hidden divs again:
     $('.mybutton').click(function () {
            $('.box').show();
            var myattr = $(this).attr('lala');
            $('.box:not([lala="' + myattr + '"])').hide();
        });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject your attribute into a attribute selector so that the end result looks like

`not('[lala="uibui"]')`

e.g.

```
$('.mybutton').click(function () {
    var myattr = $(this).attr('lala');
    $(".box[lala]").not('[lala="' + myattr + '"]').hide();
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/tt1upb9o/

It can be simplified to just

```
$('.mybutton').click(function () {
    var myattr = $(this).attr('lala');
    $('.box:not([lala="' + myattr + '"])').hide();
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/tt1upb9o/2/

Or even down to this (but now less readable):

```
$('.mybutton').click(function () {
    $('.box:not([lala="' + $(this).attr('lala') + '"])').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".box").not('[lala = "'+myattr+'"]').hide();
```